# a-frame converts my SVG into a pixel-image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, aframe

I have a < a-sphere> with an SVG wrapped around but it shows pixel. However, it seems like a-frame doesn't support `Vectorgraphics`.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/canvg/canvg is also interesting? It can use the `svg` of the `DOM` and render it to a `canvas`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try drawing the svg onto a `canvas` element, and then turning the canvas into a [texture using threejs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader):

**html**

```
<a-box svg-load></a-box>
```

**js**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('svg-load', {
    init: function() {
        // grab the canvas element
        var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas')
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create an image, which will contain the svg data
        var img = new Image();

        // this will be triggered when the provided .svg is loaded
        img.onload = () => {
          // draw the image on the canvas
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);

          // create the texture and material
          let texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
          texture.needsUpdate = true;
          let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });

          // grab the mesh, replace the material, dispose the old one
          let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
          let tmp = mesh.material
          mesh.material = material
          tmp.dispose()
          }
        // provide the .svg file as the image source 
        img.src = "file.svg";
    }
)}
```

Glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-svgtocanvas)

---

You can also provide the [canvas as a material source](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#canvas-textures), but it still looks glitchy to me.

```
<a-box material="src: my-canvas">
```

Comment: Can it be parametric to receive image path?
<a-box svg-load="file.svg"></a-box>